Comparing linear slopes between two scatterplot matrices
Below is a reproducible example of code that produces a dataset and plot roughly similar to what I am working on. The dataset is comprised of multiple columns for gene transcript abundance values and a column for a binary treatment variable.
library(GGally)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
n <- 30 

treatment <- factor(rep(c("Group1", "Group2"), each = n)) 
    # binary grouping variable 

col1_group1 <- rnorm(n, mean = 50, sd = 15) 
col1_group2 <- rnorm(n, mean = 50, sd = 8)

col2_group1 <- 0.6 * col1_group1 + rnorm(n, sd = 7)
col2_group2 <- 0.4 * col1_group2 + rnorm(n, sd = 4)
col3_group1 <- 0.5 * col1_group1 + rnorm(n, sd = 7)
col3_group2 <- 0.3 * col1_group2 + rnorm(n, sd = 4)
col4_group1 <- 0.7 * col2_group1 + rnorm(n, sd = 7)
col4_group2 <- 0.5 * col2_group2 + rnorm(n, sd = 4)
col5_group1 <- 0.8 * col3_group1 + rnorm(n, sd = 7)
col5_group2 <- 0.6 * col3_group2 + rnorm(n, sd = 4)
col6_group1 <- 0.6 * col4_group1 + rnorm(n, sd = 7)
col6_group2 <- 0.4 * col4_group2 + rnorm(n, sd = 4)

dat <- data.frame(
  treatment = treatment,
  col1 = c(col1_group1, col1_group2),
  col2 = c(col2_group1, col2_group2),
  col3 = c(col3_group1, col3_group2),
  col4 = c(col4_group1, col4_group2),
  col5 = c(col5_group1, col5_group2),
  col6 = c(col6_group1, col6_group2))

ggpairs(dat, columns = 2:7, 
        lower = list(continuous = wrap("smooth", method = "lm", 
                        se=FALSE)),
        diag = NULL, switch = "both", 
        ggplot2::aes(colour = treatment))


A couple of key characteristics of the data before I describe what I want to achieve in further detail:

the genes are all correlated with each other to some degree and are therefore not independent from one another (i.e. models with more than one gene predictor pose significant multicollinearity problems)
in visualizing the bivariate relationships between the genes grouped by treatment, it is clear that Group A and Group B have equal correlations and unequal covariances (I also have statistical evidence for this in my real data set by means of cortest.mat() for unpaired samples from the psych package and Box's M Test). Unequal covariance poses another problem with many model approaches.
all genes are normally distributed

Now, what I am interested in doing is testing whether the matrix of slopes for Group 1 is equal to the matrix of slopes for Group 2. Well, more specifically in my real dataset, I actually want to test whether the vector (?) of slopes for one of the genes in particular compared to the rest of the genes for Group 1 is equal to that of Group 2, as this is a trend that is very obvious to me when I visualize my real data, and as such a trend may have biological relevance. But I am thinking that my solution to this more specific problem may be derived from methods of comparing matrices.
Some other thoughts:

I understand how interaction terms and contrasts work. I am not interested in running individual lm(col_2 ~ col_1*treatment, data=dat) for each gene. This could pose collinearity issues anyway, since treatment affects all genes. I am also motivated to maximize statistical power because my sample sizes are small, which is why I would like a test that uses as much of the data as possible.
while a multivariate multiple regression approach does use all of the data in a single test and appears promising at first glance (i.e. lm(c(col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5) ~ col_1*treatment, data=dat)), unequal covariances are a significant problem here. And collinearity is still a potential problem.
Not that this is the best logic to use (forgive me, I am a biologist, not a statistician), but if one can compare covariance of two matrices, shouldn't comparing slopes be a simple extension of this, considering slopes are directly related to covariances?


When you say that you want to test "that the matrix of slopes for Group 1 is equal to the matrix of slopes for Group 2", is this a test of mean difference or a test of variance? Why not, for instance, just use a weighted t-test?

I am looking for a test comparing the slope values themselves. The slope value characterizes how the genes are increasing together. Say, in examining just the scatterplot for gene 1 (x axis) vs gene 2 (y axis), Group 1 has a slope of 1, indicating that a 1 unit increase in gene 1 corresponds to a 1 unit increase in gene 2. If Group 2 has a slope of 2 (steeper), this indicates that a 1 unit increase in gene 1 corresponds to a 2 unit increase in gene 2. This is biologically meaningful, and I cannot get the same information from comparisons of means or variances.

So a paired t-test then?

I'm unfortunately not following, unless you are suggesting I manually extract slopes from the fits of Group 1 and Group 2 and compare them using a t test. Can you elaborate?

@Dom is your question whether the average slope differs between the groups? Or maybe whether the slopes are more similar than expected? Or something else?

@DavidB thanks for your answer and comment! My question is whether all the slopes of Group 1 pairs, taken together, are equal to all the slopes of Group 2 pairs, taken together. In my real data, I hypothesize that they are NOT equal. The way I am thinking about it, if each group has 15 pairs plots, each group has 15 slopes values with associated error around those values. I was hoping for an analysis which will compare the 15 slopes from Group A to the 15 slopes from Group B in a pairwise manner while accounting for the error around those slopes (for more statistical power).

@Dom I've updated my answer. There is no generic method for modeling this kind of multi-collinearity. There are some field-specific methods that make field-specific assumptions (e.g., kinship matrices in population genetics). The best you can do is compute the statistic you're interested in, and then compute a p-value with permutations. Just make sure that all of your permutations are valid - in my example I assume that all rows in dat are equally independent.

If I understand you correctly, you are saying that the slopes for the two groups look very similar across the different comparisons, and you want to test whether this is significant. There is no established test for this, but you can use a permutation to compute a valid p-value. Essentially, this entails randomizing treatment assignment, but nothing else, thereby maintaining all of the multi-collinearity you noticed. Note that if the structure of your actual data is more complicated than this, then you may need to do a fancy permutation (for example this assumes that all rows in your data are equally independent).
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# computes all the pairwise correlations
get.cors  = function(cor.mat){  
    cors = cor(cor.mat %>% dplyr::select(starts_with("col")))
    cors[lower.tri(cors)]
}

# returns the correlation between the two group vectors
compute.sim = function(input.data){ 
    c1 = input.data %>% dplyr::filter(treatment == "Group1") %>%   
    get.cors() 
    c2 = input.data %>% dplyr::filter(treatment == "Group2") %>% 
    get.cors()

    cor(c1, c2)
}

# the true correlation
true.cor = compute.sim(dat)
true.cor
[1] 0.6965813

# run some permutations
perm.num = 1000
null.cors = sapply(c(1:perm.num), function(X){
  temp.dat = dat
  # treatment is randomized, everything else is the same
  temp.dat$treatment = sample(temp.dat$treatment, 
     size = length(temp.dat$treatment), replace = FALSE)
  compute.sim(temp.dat)
})

# plot the null - blue is the true correlation
hist(null.cors, breaks=100)
abline(v = true.cor, col="blue", lwd=3)



# p is the number of null correlations larger than the true 
# correlation, divided by the number of permutations
sum( abs(null.cors) > abs(true.cor))/perm.num
[1] 0.353

With your example data, the similarity in the effects between the two treatments is not any larger than expected than if the groups did not differ at all (it's pure multi-collinearity. Multi-collinearity is weird, and typical expectations for what constitutes a 'large' effect are usually quite wrong. This is a common issue across a lot of fields. Ecology has a variety of ways to address it that take advantage of the spatial location of the samples to generate nulls (called a 'spin-test').
EDIT
OP has clarified that they are interested in whether the slopes differ. To test that, we can adopt the same procedure as above, but compute the difference in the means. Because of the multi-collinearity, SEs, t-values, etc. are of no use, so we aren't even going to bother computing them. But, we can still use permutation to compute a valid p-value. Note however, that since we are comparing means, the scale is going to be super important. This only works if the slopes are all on the same scale, hence why I am using a correlation.

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# computes all the pairwise correlations
get.cors  = function(cor.mat){
  cors = cor(cor.mat %>% dplyr::select(starts_with("col")))
  cors[lower.tri(cors)]
}

# returns the difference between the two group vectors
compute.sim = function(input.data){
  c1 = input.data %>% dplyr::filter(treatment == "Group1") %>% 
    get.cors()
  c2 = input.data %>% dplyr::filter(treatment == "Group2") %>%  
    get.cors()
  
 mean(c2) - mean(c1)
}

# the true difference
true.diff = compute.sim(dat)
true.diff 
[1]  -0.3167271

# plot the groups
boxplot(dat %>% dplyr::filter(treatment == "Group1") %>% get.cors(),
        dat %>% dplyr::filter(treatment == "Group2") %>% get.cors())


Visually, the magnitude of the correlations differ between the groups, but is it significant?

# run some permutations
perm.num = 1000
null.cors = sapply(c(1:perm.num), function(X){
  temp.dat = dat
  # treatment is randomized, everything else is the same
  temp.dat$treatment = sample(temp.dat$treatment, 
     size = length(temp.dat$treatment), replace = FALSE)
  compute.sim(temp.dat)
})

# plot the null - blue is the true difference
hist(null.cors, breaks=100)
abline(v = true.diff ,col="blue", lwd=3)


The difference appears to be larger than expected by chance, just barely.
sum( abs(null.cors) > abs(true.cor))/perm.num
[1] 0.047

And the p-value is just barely <0.05. If this were a real analysis, I would increase perm.num to 10000 just be sure this was really significant.
Edit
Just for fun, let's put a 95% confidence interval on this, using a bootstrap resampling approach. NB this 95% CI cannot be converted into a SE.
# run bootstraps
perm.num = 1000
boot.out = sapply(c(1:perm.num), function(X){
  temp.dat = dat
    # resample rows at random, with replacement
  temp.dat = temp.dat[sample(c(1:length(temp.dat$treatment)), 
    size = length(temp.dat$treatment), replace = TRUE),]
  compute.sim(temp.dat)
})

# get the confidence interval
ci = quantile(boot.out, probs = c(0.025, 0.975))
ci
2.5%       97.5% 
  -0.53611747 -0.07121417 

# red is the CI
hist(null.cors, breaks=100, xlim = c(-.6,.6))
abline(v = true.diff, col="blue", lwd=3)
abline(v = ci[1], col="red", lwd=3)
abline(v = ci[2], col="red", lwd=3)



We see that even though the difference may appear large, our CI is also very large and nearly intersects 0 (aligning with our large p-value).
